# The curve of intersection of $ x^6+y^8+z^7-3xyz=0 $ and $xy+yz+xz-3z^4=0$ has parametric equations $x=f(t), y=g(t),z=t$, find $f'(1),g'(1)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The curve of intersection of the two surfaces $ x^6+y^8+z^7-3xyz=0 $ and $xy+yz+xz-3z^4=0$ has parametric equations $x=f(t), y=g(t),z=t$.

The question asks to find $f'(1),g'(1)$ and the tangent line to the curve of intersection at (1,1,1).

Now to find $f'(1), g'(1)$ the naive way would be to differentiate both equations wrt t and then try to solve for f'(1),g'(1) by plugging in 1 for t. However, we still don't know what x and y are when t=1. Now I know when z=1, x=1,y=1 as well but we don't know whether other values of x and y might also be possible when z=1.. Any help? Thanks

Comment: Are you allowed to use a CAS program such as Maple or Mathematica? If so, it's not too hard.

Comment: No sir I am not.

Comment: Is it a problem from a book? If so, which one? Also, what's the title of the course?

Comment: This is a multivariable calculus course.The problem was given as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F=x^6+y^8+z^7-3xyz=0$ and $G=xy+yz+xz-3z^4=0$

$\nabla F=(6x^5-3yz,8y^7-3xz,7z^6-3xy)$ and $\nabla G=(y+z,x+z,x+y-12z^3)$ are vectors normals to each of the surfaces $F=0$ and $G=0$. So, with $P=(1,1,1)$, a point in the intersection of the surfaces, we have

$u=\nabla F(P)=(3,5,4)$ and $v=\nabla G(P)=(2,2,-10)$. Then $u\times v$ is tangent to the curve intersection of the surfaces in $P$ (as $u$ and $v$ are both perpendicular to the curve and their cross product is perpendicular to both)

$u\times v=(-58,38,-4)$

By other side, we know that a vector tangent to the curve is $T=(f'(t),g'(t),1)$, So is $u\times v=kT$ for some $k$

$\begin{cases}
 kf'(1)=-58\\
 kg'(1)=38\\
 k=-4
\end{cases}$

Leading to $f'(1)=29/2$ and $g'(1)=-19/2$

Comment: You have f'(1)= -68k and k= -4 so f'(1) would be -68(-4)= 272, not -68/-4= 17.

Comment: The result is ok, the equations are wrong. I fix them.

Comment: @Rafa Budría: Some corrections are needed:  
$\;1{:}\;$It should be $\displaystyle{v=\nabla G(P)}$.  
$\;2{:}\;$It should be $(2,2,-10)$, not  $(2,2,-12)$.  
$\;3{:}\;$The later steps need to be adjusted accordingly.